# How to check a value from multiple nodes with the same name and then use the child within that

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xpath, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to extract the value from [this XML table](https://pastebin.com/3SvV2TpZ)

I need to check first if the ID in one of the FreeCode nodes is pTRAFC50. If it is indeed pTRAFC50, I would then pull the value from the Value child node inside FreeCode.

I tried using [7], but it does not work

```
case when EXTRACTVALUE(XmlType(o.Xml), '/Equity/FreeCode[7]/@ID[7]') = 'pTRAFC50'
case when EXTRACTVALUE(XmlType(o.Xml), '/Equity/FreeCode[7]/@ID[7]') = 'pTRAFC50'
```

I expect to be able to pull NA to my extract if the node is 'pTRAFC50'.

Comment: Please do not post images of code/text. Nobody can run that. Edit the question and post the XML as text. thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry. I updated it now.

Answer (score 1):

Try it using this pattern:

```
/Equity/FreeCode[@ID = 'pTRAFC50']/@Value
```

Comment: case when EXTRACTVALUE(XmlType(o.Xml), '/Equity/FreeCode[7]/@Value[7]') = 'pTRAFC50' then 'MATCH' else EXTRACTVALUE(XmlType(o.Xml), '/Equity/FreeCode/[@ID = 'pTRAFC50']/@Value')  end as ReasonCode

But it still does not work.

Comment: How would I be able to specify which node to check? My code does not seem to work? case when EXTRACTVALUE(XmlType(o.Xml), '/*/FreeCode[7]/@ID[7]') = 'pTRAFC50' then 'MATCH' else EXTRACTVALUE(XmlType(o.Xml), '/*/FreeCode[7]/@Value')  end as ReasonCode,

Comment: You can see in the example given below by p3consulting how the XPath I gave works. The query returns the value `NA`, as expected.

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately it still returns nothing on Oracle SQL.   EXTRACTVALUE(XmlType(o.Xml), '/Equity/FreeCode[7]/@Value') as ReasonCode,

Comment: Using the sample created by p3consluting using Oracle 11g R2 works fine, see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7bc0ee/5158 Maybe your input data doesn't match?

Answer (score 1):

```
with data(xml) as(
    select xmltype(
q'~<Equity ID="TRCL000000007000" Side="1" Ccy="USD" OrderType="5" TimeInForce="2" AggKey="-886312559405477673" AvgPx="10" CumQty="400" LeavesQty="400" Stat="1" TxnTm="0001-01-01T00:00:00" AutoAllocate="true" PmOrderType="5" PlacedQty="800" LastUpdateTm="2023-04-24T10:44:52.8099417Z" CreatedTm="2023-04-24T10:41:52.8472202Z" OrdFlags="88" Trader="371" Owner="371" LastFillTm="2023-04-24T10:44:52.488" DealDeskID="SP-EQUITY" DimDeskID="SP-EQUITY" PortfolioMasterID="2" PortCcy="SGD" FirstPortArriveTm="2023-04-24T10:38:24.2358771Z" FirstPlaceTm="2023-04-24T10:42:35.3101154Z" FirstPortAcceptTm="2023-04-24T10:41:52.8472202Z" LastTxt="" LastPortMgrComment="" MultiplePortMgrComments="false" MultipleComments="false" PortGrp="INDAH-LPF" PortAcct="INDAH-LPSEAC" PortMgr="EQ - Tan Lee Tee" PortName="LP SPORE EQUITY ACTIVE FN" ModPor="EQ_SPORE" ModPorName="EQ - Singapore Equity" InvestorID="" CustodyIK="0" PmBrokerHasMultipleValues="false" PmCptyHasMultipleValues="false" RevID="000">
  <Hdr ObjectVersion="1" />
  <Instrmt DimSecID="V US" SecIK="20227" MIC="XNYS" AstClass="EQU" Sym="V US" ID="B2PZN04" Src="2" SecTyp="CS" Exch="NYS" Desc="VISA INC-CLASS A SHARES" CFICode="ESXXXX" BrdLots="100" SecSubTyp="COM_STK" Acronym="XNYS" CountryName="United States of America (the)" QuotFac="1" QuotType="1" QuoteType="1" Country="US" ExcIK="672" DimInstrumentType="5" MarketISOCountryCode="US" AdjustEffectiveDate="false" AdjustTerminationDate="false" AdjustPeriodEndDates="false">
    <AID AltID="US92826C8394" AltIDSrc="4" />
    <AID AltID="92826C839" AltIDSrc="1" />
    <AID AltID="B2PZN04" AltIDSrc="2" />
    <AID AltID="V US Equity" AltIDSrc="A" />
  </Instrmt>
  <OrdQty Qty="800" />
  <Pty R="11" ID="EQ - Tan Lee Tee" />
  <Portfolios />
  <FreeCode ID="pSECFC121" Value="BBG000PSKYX7" />
  <FreeCode ID="pORDERFC2" Value="" />
  <FreeCode ID="pORDERFC9" Value="TEST" />
  <FreeCode ID="pTRAFC42" Value="" />
  <FreeCode ID="pORDERFC1" Value="" />
  <FreeCode ID="pTRAFC4" Value="" />
  <FreeCode ID="pTRAFC50" Value="NA" />
  <FreeCode ID="pORDERFC19" Value="SUJIT" />
  <MatchingRules NettingRuleHasMultipleValues="false" BrokerNettingRuleHasMultipleValues="false" />
  <DkText />
</Equity>~') from dual
)
select xmlquery(
    '/Equity/FreeCode[@ID="pTRAFC50"]/@Value'
    passing xml
    returning content
).getStringVal() as res_query,
extractvalue(xml, '/Equity/FreeCode[@ID="pTRAFC50"]/@Value') as res_extract
from data;

RES_QUERY RES_EXTRACT
-------------------------
NA  NA
```